# Es posible capturar un evento de boton Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Muy buenas a todos, quiero consultarles si es posible saber cuando alguien esta presionando un botón en tkinter ?

tengo estas funciones, y lo que pasa es que cuando presiono el botón 2(b1) debería cambiar su color y su texto, pero el que cambia sus configuraciones es b0 y b0 tiene que cambiar sus configuraciones solo cuando sea presionado

```
    def botonesCorrectoIncorrectos():

       if b0.:
          b0.config(text="Bien", fg="white", bg="green")           
       elif b1:
          b1.config(text="Mal", fg="white", bg="red")

    
    def botones():
       global b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8
       b0 = Button(cuadro_grid, text="Click", height=2, width=5, command=botonesCorrectoIncorrectos)
       b0.place(x=2, y=4)
       b1 = Button(cuadro_grid, text="Click", height=2, width=5, command=botonesCorrectoIncorrectos)
       b1.place(x=2, y=57)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que pude observar es que si bien la lógica esta bien, Python no registra el botón presionado, sino que "simplemente" ejecuta la función, todavía no entiendo muy bien por qué. Al llamar a la función: "botonesCorrectoIncorrectos", no hace caso a las condiciones.

Por otra parte si quisieras agregar un parametro:

```
b0 = Button(... , ... , ... , ... , command=botonesCorrectoIncorrectos(param))
```

ejecutaría la función manteniendo el boton con las caracteristicas que le especificaste en la primer condición.

Finalmente: Logré hacer correr tu script agregandole una pequeña función a la sección command. Esta función es lambda. Lambda va a ejecutar lo que se encuentre luego de que la declaramos solo si se la llama. No antes. Entonces ahora si podemos incluir un parametro.

Te dejo el script con el que hice mis pruebas y espero que te sirva.

```
botonera = [None,None]
def botonesCorrectoIncorrectos(i):

   if i==0:
      botonera[0].config(text="Bien", fg="white", bg="green")           
   elif i==1:
      botonera[1].config(text="Mal", fg="white", bg="red")

    
def botones():
    botonera[0] = Button(window, text="Click", height=2, width=5, command=lambda: botonesCorrectoIncorrectos(0))
    botonera[0].place(x=2, y=4)
    botonera[1] = Button(window, text="Click", height=2, width=5, command=lambda: botonesCorrectoIncorrectos(1))
    botonera[1].place(x=2, y=57)

botones()
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvió